# hydraulic pressure per cylinder, see below

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

when providing 2800 psi pressure to 6 hydraulic cylinders with .196 area of each cylinder what is clamping force on each cylinder. F=Pressure *area so 2800 x .196 is 548.8 psi or is it 548.8 /6 = 91,46 psi per cylinder ?

Comment: Pressure is Force / Area. But what do you mean by clamping force? How do the rams act? Suggest a diagram would help your explanation here.

Comment: F = P*A or 2800 lbf/in^2 * 0.196 in^2 = 548.8 lbf